# how to stop Jodit from wrapping elements in <p> when inserting HTML

Tags: jodit

How to reproduce:

1. in javascript console, set html to `asdf`. My code is something like: `editor.setEditorValue('asdf')`
2. toggle into source mode
3. I see `<p>asdf</p>`. I expect to see only `asdf`.

Attempted solutions

1. Configure `enter: 'br'`

This does actually work, solves the problem. But introduces a new problem, which is I want the HTML to be `<p></p>` when the user creates a new paragraph.

2. Configure `enter: 'br'` with `enterBlock: 'p'`

doesn't change anything from #1.

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved it. Maybe someone can help me verify.

I initialized editor with `enter: 'br'`. This prevents the editor from adding 'p' to every non-p wrapped element.

Then when I set the HTML of the editor, I make sure to edit the options `editor.options.enter = 'p'` so that new blocks are paragraphs.

Weirdly, when I set the HTML again (even with enter = 'p'), Jodit respects the HTML and doesn't add extra paragraph tags to elements without a wrapper